# Mysql Queries Error Inside a While Loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a **while loop** from a query called **$result**.

Inside this while loop I have two other queries **$anchors1** and **$anchors2**

The first one retrieves the **first 2 rows**;

The second one should retrieve the **following ones using an offset**.

**For some reason the queries seem to interact one another, not displaying the 3 row and pulling a duplicate row which should not be there.**

**Is there any way this queries would interfere?** 
If I delete the first one, the second query works. Same vice versa.

The platform is Wordpress.

```
while($slice = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $i++;   

    if($enable_position1 == 'y' && $i == $position[0]): 

        $anchors1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anchors WHERE site_url = '$site_current' LIMIT 3"); 
        while($anc = mysql_fetch_assoc($anchors)){
        $site_anchor = $anc['site_anchor']; 
        $site_current = $anc['site_current'];
        echo '<li><a href="'.$site_current.'" title="'.$site_anchor.'" target="_self">'.$site_anchor.'</a></li>';
        }

    elseif($enable_position2 == 'y' && $i == $position[1]): 

        $anchors2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anchors WHERE site_url = '$site_current' LIMIT 999 OFFSET 3"); 
        while($anc2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($anchors2)){
        $site_anchor2 = $anc2['site_anchor']; 
        $site_current2 = $anc2['site_current'];
        echo '<li><a href="'.$site_current2.'" title="'.$site_anchor2.'" target="_self">'.$site_anchor2.'</a></li>';
        } 

    else:

         the_post();

    endif; 

}
```

Ty very much!

Comment: In your second query, surely `OFFSET 3` would result in the third row in the unlimited resultset being returned as the first row of the limited resultset. Don't you need to change it to `OFFSET 4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second query, you're using the variable `$site_current`, which is set in the first query's block. Depending on how your application is designed, that could be causing the interference. I think you meant to put `$site_current2` there.

Comment: That worked, ty:) This is strange but $site_current has the same value (it's a multiplatform application). What I did was $site_current2 = $site_current; and the applied the change suggested by you. Why would It interfere?

Comment: Probably because you're rewriting the variable at every iteration of the first loop. Is `$site_current` coming from some other part of the application? You should avoid rewriting variables, they tend to cause bugs like this one.